# SVN: How to run a scheduled batch file to update project using Eclipse and Subversive?

Tags: batch-file, svn, automation, subversive

Need assistance writing a batch script to automatically update a project form SVN using specifically Eclipse/Subversive and not other clients such as TortoiseSVN or SilkSVN.

Comment: It might be able to be done but I have no clue what those programs are. You are going to have to provide some code on how it all works. Please update your question.

Comment: @Squashman  I need to open eclipse from a batch script and use a command to run Subversive's update command for a project. Subversive is an SVN integrated plug-in for Eclipse IDE. I cannot find any information on Subversive commands using batch to write the code.

Comment: A batch file is not going to be able to control a program that has a graphical interface.

Comment: I have not gone there, but it would seem possible that a cmd script could use a .class file from `C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\944\0\.cp\org\apache\subversion\javahl` to co or up a project. Might require digging into the Subversive source.

Comment: @Squashman eclipse has a command line interface as well.